# How do I build has_many: :through objects on a join table where the parent already exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I the following models in my rails app:

```
class SaleContact < ActiveRecord::Base
 validates :key_contact_id, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: :sales_opportunity_id, message: "Contact already added!" }
 validates :sales_opportunity_id, presence: true
 belongs_to :key_contact, inverse_of: :sale_contacts
 belongs_to :sales_opportunity, inverse_of: :sale_contacts
 has_many :phone_numbers, :through => :key_contact
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :phone_numbers
end
```

This is the join table - as you can see it belongs_to both key_contacts and sales_opportunities. I'm trying to create a sale_contact from the sales_opportunity screen by selecting a key_contact (assume it's already been added). I would also like the ability to add a phone_number at the same time using fields_for and nested attributes.

```
class KeyContact < ActiveRecord::Base
 validates :first_name, :last_name, :company_id, presence: true
 has_many :phone_numbers, dependent: :destroy
 belongs_to :company
 has_many :sales_opportunities, :through => :sale_contacts
 has_many :sale_contacts, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Assume I've already created the key_contact and assigned it to the company that owns it.

```
class PhoneNumber < ActiveRecord::Base
 validates :number, :key_contact_id, presence: true
 belongs_to :key_contact
end
```

Nothing magical here - just a very basic model for a phone number.

On the sales_opportunity page I can load a modal that adds a new sale_contact. It's a bootstrap modal loaded by AJAX, but I don't think that matters much (I've only included the form parts for brevity):

```
<%= form_for(@sale_contact, :html => {role: :form, 'data-model' => 'sale_contact'}, remote: true) do |f| %>
      <% if @sale_contact.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@sale_contact.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this sale_contact from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
          <% @sale_contact.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
          <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>

      <div class="form-group" id= "contact_error">
        <%= f.label :key_contact_id, :class => "control-label" %>
        <div id="contact_select">
        <%= f.collection_select :key_contact_id, @sales_opportunity.company.key_contacts(:full_name), :id, :full_name %>
        </div>
        <span class="warning-block"></span>
        <span class="help-block"></span>
      </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :role, :class => "control-label" %>
          </br>
            <%= f.select(:role, options_for_select(@roles.collect { |r| [r[0].humanize, r[0]] }, selected: @sale_contact.role), {}) %>
          <span class="help-block"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :preference, :class => "control-label" %>
          </br>
            <%= f.select(:preference, options_for_select(@preferences.collect { |r| [r[0].humanize, r[0]] }, selected: @sale_contact.preference), {}) %>
          <span class="help-block"></span>
        </div>

        <%= f.fields_for(:phone_numbers) do |phone| %>
            <div class="form-group">
              <%= phone.label :number, "Phone Number", :class => "control-label" %>
            </br>
              <%= phone.text_field :number, :placeholder => "Enter phone number (optional)" %>
              <span class="help-block"></span>
            </div>
        <% end %>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.hidden_field :sales_opportunity_id, :value => @sales_opportunity.id %>
        </div>
          <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-large btn-success", data: { disable_with: "Submitting..." }%>
    <% end %>
```

And from my sale_contact_controller new action:

```
  def new
   @sale_contact = SaleContact.new
   @sale_contact.phone_numbers.build
   @sales_opportunity = SalesOpportunity.find(params[:sales_opportunity_id])
   @company = @sales_opportunity.company
   @roles = SaleContact.roles
   @preferences = SaleContact.preferences
   render :modal_form
  end

   def sale_contact_params
     params.require(:sale_contact).permit(:key_contact_id, :sales_opportunity_id, :role, :preference, phone_numbers_attributes: [:number, :id])
    end
```

Using this setup the modal pops into view and has the correct fields (both for sale_contact and phone_number), but will not save either of these models. I'm sure it's something to do with the way I've set up the new action in the controller, but I can't quite work out what as most articles online don't cover this scenario.

From what I can work out:
1.) KeyContact exists and is in the database, but until the SaleContact is saved, it doesn't know anything about the KeyContact.
2.) PhoneNumber is built successfully (I tested this in the rails console and it's fine), but without the KeyContact info passing through I get the 422 Unprocessable Entity error)
3.) I presume the failure of the PhoneNumber.save method is causing the whole transaction to fail and rollback.

Stack trace:

```
Started POST "/sale_contacts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-11-24 15:46:19 +0800
Processing by SaleContactsController#create as JS
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "sale_contact"=>{"key_contact_id"=>"92", "role"=>"not_known", "preference"=>"unknown", "phone_numbers_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"number"=>"89101112"}}, "sales_opportunity_id"=>"65"}, "commit"=>"Save"}
SalesOpportunity Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "sales_opportunities".* FROM "sales_opportunities"  WHERE "sales_opportunities"."id" = $1  ORDER BY close_date ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 65]]
Company Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies"  WHERE "companies"."id" = $1  ORDER BY company_name ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 107]]
 (0.3ms)  BEGIN
SaleContact Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "sale_contacts"  WHERE ("sale_contacts"."key_contact_id" = 92 AND "sale_contacts"."sales_opportunity_id" = 65) LIMIT 1
 (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 16ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 1.7ms)
```

The SaleContact doesn't exist in the database as I can't find it either on page reload or when querying via the rails console.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'm pretty sure it's to do with the way I've set up the relationships and the build function, but I'm currently drawing a blank.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the create method for sales contact will look like this:-

```
# sale_contact_controller create method:
def create
    @sale_contact = SaleContact.new(sale_contact_params)
    if @sale_contact.save
        # do something
    else
        # do somthing
    end  
end
```

You don't need to do explicitly PhoneNumber.save. Phone numbers will also create with sale contact.

Comment: Yes, the create controller looks like that - with a few other related objects and enums declared too. The issue is that the way the new and create controller actions is configured at the moment isn't working - hence the stack trace. It's either the way I'm trying to build the objects or the way the relationships are declared in the models as far as I can tell, but I'm drawing a blank at the moment. Thanks for your help.